# SharePoint Online, change Logo for one page (not for web. on Page Layout or Masterpage, or with js..)

Tags: master-page, site-logo

I have web with site logo (top left corner), but need to have one Page with different logo (on same web). This task looked simple but for me it isn't(

I have custom master page, page layout (I changed parent master page inside tags), and Page in "Pages" library.

I tried to play with js/jQuery, for example something like this..

```
jQuery("#DeltaSiteLogo").empty().html('<a id="ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" title="Home" class="ms-siteicon-a" href="/"><img id="ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2" class="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" src="my-logo.png" alt="Home" data-themekey="#"></a>').css("visibility", "visible");
```

Tried CSS trick:

http://thomasdaly.net/2016/08/09/change-default-sharepoint-site-logo-css-trick-great-for-office-365/

Also tried to replace logo in masterpage, but I don't see changes even if I publish master page oO

https://sharepoint.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/how-to-change-the-logo-on-your-sharepoint-2013-site/

How do You do it?....

Comment: Can you please provide some examples of your page? It would be easier to help if you showed if it was a modern experience or a classic.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for comment! Page is Classic..

Had no better idea then do something like this:

```
    // Replace logo
    jQuery(".ms-siteicon-img").attr("src", "my-logo.png");

    // Show after delay
    setTimeout(function (){
        jQuery("#DeltaSiteLogo").addClass("animated fadeIn").css("visibility", "visible"); 
    }, 2000);
```

there is manual delay for 2 seconds. In CSS there is

```
#DeltaSiteLogo {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is ugly, but I don't know how to replace this logo on layouts/masterpage level..

Comment: This is not best answer. If You find how to change logo on layout/masterpage level, I'll mark it as answer